# JavaFX - removing window shadow in crunchbang linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx

What i am try to do is making application scene transparent. I googled it and find some solution like this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    setRoot((BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/Home.fxml")));
    getRoot().setEffect( null );
    javafx.scene.Scene scene = new javafx.scene.Scene(getRoot(), 800,500, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

This solution works on windows. But it puts shadow in my crunchbang linux.

[image: screenshot]

Do you know how to remove this shadow?

Thank you...

Comment: I wonder if it's JavaFX or your window manager creating the shadow?

Comment: Thank you for reply. It's exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit Settings > Compositor > Edit Compositing Settings  shadow line to false.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really check your problem cause I don't have your fxml to test it, but I created fast a test program and got a transparent window in Linux. Try putting this also:

```
scene.setFill(null);
```

Reference: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/TRANSPARENTwindow.htm

Comment: did u try to adapt the code from the reference for your needs? did you also tried just to take the code from the reference and just run it and see if u still have that shadow?

Comment: Yes, i did all the way on web.